# ERROR: Failed to buld gem native extension?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, riemann

I am installing **riemann** monitoring tool on my PC. I run the following command from terminal:

Command:

```
sudo gem install riemann-tools
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing riemann-tools:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

            /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from extconf.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

A similar error comes when installing **riemann-dash** but riemann-client get installed successfully.

I am using `Ububtu 12.10`. 
I read online about such errors and it had something with ruby version, but I am not able to figure out the reason for this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When you get the `Failed to build gem native extension` error, the fist thing to check is that you have the native development tools installed.  The C compiler, etc.  On Centos: `yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'`, on Ubuntu, try: `sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall`

Comment: @Daiku: I did `sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall` but still I get the same error.

Comment: @Daiku: It's working now. I removed sudo from `sudo gem install riemann-tools`. Strange I guess.

Comment: That is odd.  Glad it's working for you.  CB.

Answer (score 3):

this solved it for me:

For Debian/Ubuntu

```
apt-get install ruby-dev zlib1g-dev
```

For RedHat/CentOS/Fedora:

```
yum install ruby-devel zlib-devel
```